# Switching Kernel Versions on Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, kernel

I am going to run a few experiments on my machine and I was interested in how my numbers would be affected by different Linux kernel versions. I have a machine running Ubuntu 18.04 and I was wondering if there is an easy way to boot with different linux kernel versions, run my benchmarks, and repeat with a different version of the kernel. Furthermore, will Ubuntu break if I try to load a different kernel? Where can I find the compatible versions?

Comment: You can use any installed kernel. Use the GRUB prompt to boot into whichever kernel you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install e.g. HWE kernels, see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack. Press Shift during boot to get to Grub menu so you can choose kernel to boot.